# Laplace transform of $y''' - 3y'' + 3y' - y = (t^2)e^t$ where $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$, $y'' = -2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Any ideas?

I got:-

$$s^3 - 2s^2 + 3s - 4/(s(s^2 + 3) + 1))$$

but I got it wrong, obviously, because it does not simplify into any inverse laplaces.

Comment: Please, anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Taking the Laplace Transform of your equation, we arrive at:

$[s^{3}y(s) - s^{2}Y(0) - sY'(0) - Y''(0)] -3[s^{2}y(s) - sY(0) -Y'(0)] + 3[sy(s)-Y(0)] -y(s) = \frac{2}{(s -1)^{3}}$

Collect like terms, do some algebra, do partial fraction expansion and this results in 
$$y(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} - \frac{1}{(s-1)^{2}} -\frac{1}{(s-1)^{3}} + \frac{2}{(s-1)^{6}}$$

Then, do the inverse Laplace Transform to arrive at $y(t)$.

Does that all make sense and you can it from there?

**Update**

$y(t) = e^{t} -te^{t} - \frac{t^{2}e^{t}}{2} + \frac{t^{5}e^{t}}{60}$

Test it against the DEQ, and IC's and verify that this is the solution.

Regard

Comment: That's exactly what I did and got L{y} = s^2 - 3s + 1/(s^3 - 3s^2 + 3s - 1). But this still does not easily simplify...

Comment: waiiit a minute! Yes it does! Is it e^-t - te^t - t^2e^t?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Solve and show y(s) and lets see where you went astray. Y(t) should have four terms when you are done. Smartphones are hard to type on! Regards

Comment: I'm lost, no worries, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: OK, I've simplified it and got L{y}(s^3 - 3s^2 + 3s - 1) - s^2 + 3s + 1 = 2/((s-1)^3) Is this right so far?

Comment: @user57190: use my answer, rewrite it, simplify, add initial conditions and add to your answer so we can see issue. Be careful with those higher order derivatives! Regards

Comment: @user57190: you're almost there.  For the free term, I got $-s^2+3 s -1$.  Now write everything in terms of powers of $s-1$ and you're there.

Comment: @user57190: Beautiful! Now, solve for y(s).

Comment: Here's the thing, I don't know how to simplify this I guess I could simplify the top to get (s-3)s + 1 but the bottom bit looks insane...

Comment: The equation should be $s-(s-1)^2 +(s-1)^3 \hat{f}(s) = 2/(s-1)^2$.

Comment: @rlgordonma, How did you get to that point?

Comment: $s^3-3 s^2+3 s-1=(s-1)^3$.

Comment: $-s^2+3 s-1=-(s-1)^2+s$

Comment: Good work, Amzoti! +++

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks!